# Redirecting output to a Text widget using multiprocessing

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, multiprocessing, python-3.4

This question is related with how I can see the outputs “`stdout`” in a Text widget in tkinter.
The outputs are produced by multiprocessing. I develop a dummy case to explain it better:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

master = tk.Tk()

notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)
notebook.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
frame1 = tk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(frame1, text='foo')

a = 0

def printing():
    global a
    a += 1
    print(a)

def do_work(s):
    time.sleep(s)
    print(s)

def button():
    List_of_works = [5,5,5,8,3,3,9,2]
    pool = ThreadPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) 

    pool.map(do_work, List_of_works)

    pool.close() 
    pool.join()

frame1_1 = Frame(frame1)

Button_1 = Button(frame1_1, text='print_1', command=printing)
Button_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
Button_2 = Button(frame1_1, text='print_2', command=button)
Button_2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)

frame1_1.pack()

frame1_2 = Frame(frame1)

Textbox = Text(frame1_2, borderwidth=3, relief='ridge')
Textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

frame1_2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


class PrintToTextbox(object): 
     def write(self, s): 
         Textbox.insert(END, s)

#sys.stdout = PrintToTextbox()
#sys.stderr = PrintToTextbox()

master.geometry('200x300')
master.mainloop()
```

As you can see, when the code is executed, we can see two buttons (`print_1` and `print_2`). When I press `print_1`, (1, 2, 3, ...) are printed in the IDLE, if you press `print_2`, a simple *multiprocessing* starts and prints values in the IDLE.

Then I try to redirect stdout to a `Text` widget. Removing the sharp symbol (`#`) (`sys.stdout = PrintToTextbox()`), when you press `print_1`, you can see the printing in the `Text` widget, but if you press `print_2`, the program doesn't print anything, and I don't know why.

Comment: Where did you see that removing `#sys.stdout = PrintToTextbox()` and `#sys.stderr = PrintToTextbox()` would redirect the output to the Text widget? Never heard about such a thing. Apart from your specific problem, your code contains potentially other problems. You're doing `Button_1 = Button(frame1_1, text='print_1', command=printing).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)`, but `grid` returns `None`, so `Button_1` is `None`, even though you may think it contains a reference to your button. Using `time.sleep` with tkinter may also not be a good idea, because it freezes the UI. Use `after`?!

Comment: First of all, thanks for your prompt response. I edit the code to modify the grid problem. The question is related with the multiprocessing module and the text widget. The target is to print in the text widget. If you remove the `#` symbol in the code, the print_1 button works fine, but the print_2 button don’t do anything due to multiprocessing module (with the `#` symbol prints in python console GUI) (this is a simplified code to explain my problem and that’s the reason to remove or don’t remove the symbol…see the behaviour of the code). I don´t know why and if there is any solution.